# How to disable network traffic on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, sniffing

I am having Windows 7 hosted on VMWare which is running on Windows7 as well. My guest W7 is using my client network card as NAT.

Now i want to monitor some traffic from some specfic website. I installed Wireshark and started capturing packets in my guest W7. I noticed that it has been capturing all the packets i.e. windows updates and all the random things which windows does in backend. Now what i want, I want traffic specific to website or say chrom or any browser.

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to disable network traffic, or just see only certain network traffic? Please clarify your question.

Comment: i want to capture traffic from specific website. it can be done either ways. so i just want to know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark has traffic monitoring options using filters.

You can filter monitored traffic from source IP to a certain destination, and origin–destination port. See: [CaptureFilters - The Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters)

Comment: How about adding some substance to your answer?